# Laravel Nova Action Fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

EDIT:

in novas ActionEvent.php class i edited the two rows fields and exceptions for the `forResourceUpdate` function:

Whats actually strange now my resource is updated but there is nothing in the ACTION EVENT table.

```
    public static function forResourceUpdate($user, $model)
{
    return new static([
        'batch_id' => (string) Str::orderedUuid(),
        'user_id' => $user->getKey(),
        'name' => 'Update',
        'actionable_type' => $model->getMorphClass(),
        'actionable_id' => $model->getKey(),
        'target_type' => get_class($model),
        'target_id' => $model->getKey(),
        'model_type' => get_class($model),
        'model_id' => $model->getKey(),
        'fields' => 'test',
        'status' => 'finished',
        'exception' => 'test',
    ]);
}
```

so i just installed Nova set up some Resources, it shows everything fine, but when i try to update any of them, i get a Database error that i cant insert NULL into `ACTION_EVENT.FIELDS`.

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/actions/defining-actions.html#action-fields

The Doc says i can define some fields in the Actions fields function , but i didnt generate any Action class not i want to. I think its some sort of default action logging?

Can i turn it off, or do i have to add some Fields somewhere?

```
<?php

namespace App\Nova;

use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ID;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest;

class Chain extends Resource
{

    public static $category = "Stammdaten";

    /**
     * The model the resource corresponds to.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $model = 'App\Model\System\Partner\Chain';

    /**
     * The single value that should be used to represent the resource when being displayed.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $title = 'id';

    /**
     * The columns that should be searched.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $search = [
        'id',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the fields displayed by the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the cards available for the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function cards(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the filters available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function filters(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the lenses available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function lenses(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the actions available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function actions(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

And The Model:

```
class Chain extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use ObservantTrait;
    use TranslationTrait;

    protected $primaryKey = 'partner_chain_id';
    protected $table = 'tbl_prm_partner_chain';
    public $sequence = 'seq_partner_chain_id';

    const CREATED_BY = 'insert_user';
    const CREATED_AT = 'insert_timestamp';

    const UPDATED_BY = 'update_user';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'update_timestamp';

    const DELETED_BY = 'delete_user';
    const DELETED_AT = 'delete_timestamp';

    protected $fillable = ['name_text', 'partner_type_id'];

    protected $dates = ['delete_timestamp', 'insert_timestamp'];
```

thats all its quit simple, thats why i have no Clue right now where i am going wrong.

Comment: What is your Laravel & Laravel nova version? Can you also provide the more error logs.

Comment: Laravel 5.7 , Nova v1.1.4. Sadly i cant provide any more error log as the first error when i try to update comes from the Database. QueryException, that he cant Insert a NULL value in a NOT NULL field: in the FIELDS column of ACTION_EVENTS. And i dont know how to set the Fields that he wants to insert there.

Comment: Can you please provide resource & eloquent model class

Comment: updated with code from nova model and model for you. There is not much to see tho.